# Update view when a push notification is received

Tags: android

I would like to update a view from within an open activity when the device receives a push notification.

When a push notification is received the `updateBalance` function is executed, 
a mysql database is queried and an amount is returned.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private void updateBalance(String messageBody) {

        h1 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                bb = msg.getData();
                String str = bb.getString("result");
                Log.d(TAG,str);

                Message msg=handler.obtainMessage()

            }
       };
       t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(h1)); 
       t.start(); 

       try {
           t.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

I have another class

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   private Handler h2;

   public MyRunnable(Handler h) {
     this.h2 = h;
  }

   @Override
   public void run() {

      String name = "w12";

      BalanceActivity NB = new BalanceActivity(name);
      Message m = Message.obtain(); 
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      b.putString("result", "10");
      m.setData(b);
      h2.sendMessage(m);

   }
}
```

I have a `MainActivity` that I would like to update after the amount is returned. How would I do this possibly with another `Handler` and `Runnable`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {       
    TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(package.name.R.id.Balance);
}
```

Comment: what the issue you are facing?

Comment: I dont know how to update the MainActivity. Would I possibly do it with another Handler and Runnable

Comment: what is h1? Is it handler of `MainActivity`?

Comment: no h1 is a handler in the activity that receives push notification

Answer (score 0):

- Try to check your activity is currently in foreground. if yes then create method where you can update your view.

> ```
> public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context context) {
>
>     Log.i(TAG, "Checking if service is running");
>
>     ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
>
>     List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
>
>     boolean isServiceFound = false;
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
>
>         if (Constants.PACKAGE.equals(services.get(i).service.getPackageName())){
>
>             if (Constants.BACKGROUND_SERVICE_CLASS.equals(services.get(i).service.getClassName())){
>                 isServiceFound = true;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     Log.i(TAG, "Service was" + (isServiceFound ? "" : " not") + " running");
>
>     return isServiceFound;
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Broadcast Receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts). Register local broadcast receiver in activity. Broadcast data when notification received.